# Save multiple screenshots using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I save screenshot from browser with this code:

```
'''
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('./google.png')
'''
```

But I want to save more than one. How can i change file name when it use once?

Comment: i have provided answer, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use adding dynamic variable to your file/screenshot name, like:

random string generator, for example:
import random
import string

```
def get_random_string(length=10):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
```

or convert time.time() to int():

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./screenshot_name{int(time.time())}.png')
```

or datetime:

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./screenshot_name{str(datetime.datetime.now())}.png')
```

so, code looks like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./screenshot_name{get_random_string()}.png')
driver.quit()
```

by the way, don't forget adding **driver.quit()** command that the end.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is always good practice to add `driver.quit()` at the end of your code to close the instance automatically.

In the following code you will take 10 screenshots of the same page!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('./google.png')

for i in range(10):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./duckduckgo{i}.png')
driver.quit()
```

The whole idea is that in this for loop the i gets inserted into the file name every single iteration. So you end up with 10 Screenshots

If you want to navigate somewhere else and then take a screenshot you can simply insert the code in the middle and then use the screenshot command with a different name:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('./google.png')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./duckduckgo1.png') #Taking screenshot with name ./duckduckgo1.png
#Some Code here
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./duckduckgo2.png') #Taking screenshot with name ./duckduckgo2.png
driver.quit()
```

Edit:
This should work for your particular use case:

```
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
num = str(datetime.datetime.now())
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('./google.png')
driver.get_screenshot_as_file(f'./duckduckgo{num}.png')
driver.quit()
```

This will name the screenshot './duckduckgo{current time}.png' such that you never have 2 files with the same name!

Comment: good solution with loop as well, I started think about adding string generator or smth like this)

Comment: actually i want to save screenshot when program start, then for next time when program start again save it in other name. not in a row!!

Comment: Okay I understand, I am working on the Edit now!

Comment: @shayanmohamadkarimi the 'Edit' Section on my post will solve your problem, please upvote my answer and mark it as correct!

Comment: it is a good idea.thank you but i don't have enough reputation to upvote.